# Radiation frequency from an accelerated charged particle

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

My understanding is that a charged particle, when accelerated emits EM radiation.  In a situation where a charged particle is briefly accelerated in a straight line it should produce a propagating electromagnetic wave.  My question is, what is the characteristic frequency of this wave, and what parameters does it depend on?

Comment: Can you make a simple drawing of acceleration vs time? Is it a square pulse, triangle, gaussian bump...?

Answer (score -1):

Wave produced by brief accelerated motion is not periodic train, but a glimmer. The concept of frequency does not apply to such a wave.

Comment: I understand that it would not be periodic, would it be more like a propagating ramp or step function?  Or what is the characteristic length of this glimmer then?

Comment: https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/radiating-charge/radiating-charge_en.html

Here is a cool simulator I found.  As you can see if you accelerate it in a straight line you get this single wave propagating out.  I am curious about the parameters that define this waves shape.

Comment: Transients are expressed as a distribution of frequencies all the time in physics, electrical engineering, acoustics, optics...  The peak frequency will be some factor of order unity times 1/t.

Comment: I clicked "*sinusoidal*" 20 minutes ago and forgot what I was doing. Nice simulator @PumpkinPie!